# Xamarin connect to Web Api

Tags: web, xamarin, service, authentication, httpclient

I am new to using Xamarin, Web APIs and HttpClient.

I have an app, I am trying to retrieve a message from a local Web Service I am running using HttpClient and display it as a simple basic start.

Here is my 'Login' button code:

```
    private async void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var txtEmail = this.FindByName<Entry>("txtEmail");
        var txtPassword = this.FindByName<Entry>("txtPassword");

        if ( txtEmail.Text == null )
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Email", "Please enter your email address!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        if (txtPassword.Text == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Password", "Please enter your password!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://82.68.3.61/api/ping");
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    await DisplayAlert("Success", json, "OK");
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my Web Application Controller code:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/ping")]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Pong!!");
    }
}
```

If I use the following: https://localhost:44309/api/ping I get the message Pong!! back, but the app doesn't do anything when I press login, why?

Comment: have you stepped through your code in the debugger to verify what is actually occurring?

Answer (score 0):

That IP seems like a public IP, you probably don't have the correct rules in your firewall/router to allow external access.

If your app runs in an emulator you can use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` to reach your host machine.

Otherwise, if you are running on a device on the same network as your host computer, then use the local IP address. Often these are in the `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` ranges.

Also, you should not use `HttpClient` in a `using` statement like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

It should be considered as a shared resource per app instance. Otherwise you will experience that you leak TCP sockets, which can result in you not being able to make new requests.